# Error while getting file MIME type

Tags: c#, mime-types

I have used the code [here](https://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/dynamically-determine-mime-types-in-c/) to get the MIME type of file.

AS

```
        public static string GetContentType(string fileName)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extension))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension);

            if (registryKey == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var value = registryKey.GetValue("Content Type") as string;

            return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value;
        }
```

But It always returns null for sql file. Any Idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sql` might has not any value named `Content Type`. You can manually add that through `regedit` tool.

Comment: Yes. But how to do that. I have a .sql folder under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
You can find it at : 
http://s18.postimg.org/9fif5qjx5/Content.jpg

Comment: Right click on the right pane > `New` > `String Value` and rename it as Content Type then set the data as `application/octet-stream` (There is no special MIME type for SQL). I suspect the same procedure should be followed for the key named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.sql`.

Comment: If you are going to do that programatically, then what's your point?

Comment: I mean that type is not present in one's machine then for sql files always returns null. So the problem arises.

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida, You can refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy(v=vs.110).aspx). You should better to keep a file for extensions that will not have a content type value in registry.